export as xlsx to the self-selected file path (react, node.js)
I use XLSX from node.js
Now I save data (array) in the appropriate format using XLSX. This works quite well like this:


        var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        const exportedData = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(exportData);
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, exportedData, "Export")

        const filename = `dateiname`;

        const filePath = `D://users/user/${filename}.xlsx`;





        XLSX.writeFile(wb,filePath , { type: "file", bookType: "xlsx" })


However, I would like to save the file in a file path that I specify. Currently the file is always saved in my local Downloads folder.
In the code above, the special characters such as ":", "/" or "" are translated as "_" and adopted as the file name. In the example above, a file is created with the name = "D___users_user_filename.xlsx". The attempt to pass a path to XLSX fails.
Attempt 1: I tried different path compositions. I once replaced the / with //. Then also with \ or with \. the same result everywhere
Attempt 2: I also passed the path via path.resolve(). Same output.
Goal:
I'm looking for a way to use XLSX to determine not only the file name but also the storage location. This is obviously not possible via the file name!...???
Or are there methods to get what you want? Alternative for XLSX?
